# required with input and javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, required

I would like to set a required before submitting but isn't work any idea? May over JS ? Thank you for your support

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr><td><input type="text" size"30" placeholder="Text " maxlength="10" id="source" required>
<button type="submit" class="formButton" id="submit">Submit</button></td></tr>

<tr><td height="20px"></td></tr>                            
<tr><td><input type="text" style="border:none" size="40" id="target" class="form69" onClick="myFunct()"></td></tr>
<tr><td height="150px"></td></tr>   

<script>
$(".formButton").click(function() {
 $(".form69").show();
});
</script>

<script>
$('#submit').click(function(){
var source = $('#source').val();
$('#target').val('text test' + source + ' text');
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a form tag. Add a form tag like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<tr><td><input type="text" size"30" placeholder="Text " maxlength="10" id="source" required>
<button type="submit" class="formButton" id="submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
</form>

<tr><td height="20px"></td></tr>                            
<tr><td><input type="text" style="border:none" size="40" id="target" class="form69" onClick="myFunct()"></td></tr>
<tr><td height="150px"></td></tr>   

<script>
$(".formButton").click(function() {
 $(".form69").show();
});
</script>

<script>
$('#submit').click(function(){
var source = $('#source').val();
$('#target').val('text test' + source + ' text');
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: this script will display the output whatever i put in the text fill. if i set a form it will submitted to nirvana like reload the page. that's why is it possible without form ?

Answer (score 2):

Your form fields must be inside of a `form` element.

Also (FYI), you don't need a separate `script` tag for each of your functions.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" size="30" placeholder="Text " maxlength="10" id="source" required>
  <button type="submit" class="formButton" id="submit">Submit</button>

  <input type="text" style="border:none" size="40" id="target" class="form69" onClick="myFunct()">
</form>

<script>
  $(".formButton").click(function() {
   $(".form69").show();
  });

  $('#submit').click(function(){
    var source = $('#source').val();
    $('#target').val('text test' + source + ' text');
  }); 
</script>
```